# Creating other shared objects like map (CMV)

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, global

We need to create an object which is accessible from the controller and widgets. Rather like how we can currently access the map object. Could anybody shed light on how this can be done?

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do this is with a singleton. I answered a similar question here:
https://github.com/cmv/cmv-app/issues/413

This will be coming out of the box in CMV soon.